# How could I use Wit.ai to get speech to text on my webpage running python script

Tags: raspbian, python, linux, speech-recognition, speech-synthesis

I want the speech to be recorded by raspberry, send it to wit.ai and then get the response on my page(wich is actually the .py script and according to which I could run my conditions). Actually its the part of my project Home Automation using raspberry. So when I say 'light on' it could do so by running the scripts. I did the lot of search on google read the docs but ...did not got my problem solved. Any help is heartly appreciated... Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use a pre-made module to communicate with Wit. Usually, searching for whatever you're trying to do along with "Python" brings up many libraries, and I found [pywit](https://github.com/wit-ai/pywit) quickly by searching for "Python Wit.ai".

Instructions and usage guidance is given there; you can install it using Pip with `pip install wit`. (`pip3` for Python 3)

You can send a request to Wit to convert speech to text as  follows:

```
from wit import Wit

client = Wit(access_token)
resp = None
with open('test.wav', 'rb') as f:
  resp = client.speech(f, None, {'Content-Type': 'audio/wav'})
print('Yay, got Wit.ai response: ' + str(resp))
```

You will of course need to integrate that into your web server, but it should be relatively straightforward to collect a WAV file from the user and return the output.